# Using UIPageViewController in storyboards

Tags: iphone, ios, storyboard, uipageviewcontroller

Is there a way to configure datasource, delegate and view controllers for UIPageViewController in storyboard without writing a code? I do see outlets for datasource and delegate in UIPageViewController, but there is no way to do connections between scenes, and no way to add additional controller into the same scene.

What is the purpose to have UIPageViewController in Interface Builder if it is not configurable at all with IB?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is fully configurable in Xcode.  You'll connect the `data-source` and `delegate` outlets to classes that inherit the appropriate protocols (`UIPageViewControllerDataSource` and `UIPageViewControllerDelegate`).

But, you must do some implementation for the two protocols - usually by accessing your model's data.  It is common, but not required, to have the controller for the UIPageView be handle these two protocols.  As:

```
@interface MyPageViewController : UIPageViewController
  <UITableViewDataSource,  UITTableViewDelegate>
...
@end
```

Comment: What is the purpose of outlets if they are not configurable through IB?

Comment: Outlets are configured though IB.  Link the UIPageView outlets to the data-source and delegate (typically your UIPageViewController subclass).  Then implement the data-source and delegate protocol methods.  In Xcode, when you create a new file that is a subclass of UIPageViewController, the Xcode template will include implementations for the protocol methods.

Comment: Apple SDK documentation - "To alter the behavior of this class, you should provide a data source and delegate. This class is not intended to be subclassed."

Comment: There is no way to set this outlets to any class through IB. Do you have any practical experience of work with this class in IB or it is just a guess?

Comment: I said 'typically' - which means 'not always'.  Create a class '@interface MyPageViewControllerDataSource : NSObject <UIPageViewControllerDataSource> ... @end'  In IB drag an 'object cube' into the object listing pane; set the type of the dragged object to `MyPageViewControllerDataSource`.  Then drag the 'data source' outlet of your UIPageViewController to the 'object cube'.  Then implement the data source methods in your newly created MyPageViewControllerDataSource.  Finally upvote this answer and checkmark it; because it is the correct answer.

Comment: Ok, I got you point. Sorry for a down-vote. Going to change it back.