# Create Relationship Segues

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, segue

How can I create a relationship segue? I would like to create a `UIViewController` subclass similar to `UITabBarController` or `UINavigationController` where, using Interface Builder, I can control + drag from a view controller to another view controller. I have tried

```
@property (nonatomic) IBOutlet NSArray *viewControllers;
@property (nonatomic) IBOutlet UIStoryboardSegue *root;
```

and also tried dragging a Container View into my view controller. When I do that, I can drag from one view controller to another but I cannot drag to more than one view controller. I also cannot find any documentation for a `UIContainerView` object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Relationship Segues are handled by Interface Builder. You cannot create them manually if the starting view controller is not one of those you mentioned. The simplest solution for your issue is to create a TabBarController and hide its tab bar in code.

Here is a quite advanced tutorial on something very similar to what you are trying to do. You may get some more ideas from it. [Advanced Storyboard Techniques](https://web.archive.org/web/20180906101106/http://www.freelancemadscience.com/fmslabs_blog/2012/9/24/advanced-storyboard-techniques.html)

EDIT:

> Thanks for the tip about using a TabBarController, but I am asking this question because I am trying to subclass UIPageViewController so that I can create the PageViewController's datasource from IB

That's an interesting idea, and here is an explained solution for that: [Using UIPageViewController in storyboards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15732919/using-uipageviewcontroller-in-storyboards) You don't have to subclass the UIPageViewController, it is against the recommendation in the documentation, too. Create a class that implements the `UIPageViewControllerDataSource` delegate. Place a "green cube" in the page view controller's listing panel and set its class to be newly created one. Then drag from the datasource outlet to this cube.

However, the pages cannot be set up visually in this way or any other. It is unfortunately not supported at all.

Comment: Those are Manual Segues. I am looking to create a Relationship Segue for my own subclass of UIViewController.

Comment: sorry I misunderstood your question first, updated the answer. Would it work for you? What can be the problem with it?

Comment: Thanks for the tip about using a TabBarController, but I am asking this question because I am trying to subclass UIPageViewController so that I can create the PageViewController's datasource from IB.

Comment: added a few more thoughs

Comment: Thanks, it's not exactly what I was looking for but it gets the job done.